# How to buffer only latest emission from rx.Observable during backpressure

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, backpressure

I have an `rx.Observable` which emits the progress of a task to `onNext()`. The `onNext()` emissions can sometimes occur so quickly that the `Observer` cannot keep up, resulting in [backpressure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure). I would like to handle the backpressure by only buffering the latest emission from the `Observable`.

For example:

- `Observable` emits **1** and `Observer` receives **1**.
- While `Observer` is still processing **1**, `Observable` emits **2**, **3**, and **4**.
- `Observer` finishes processing **1** and begins processing **4** (emissions **2** and **3** are dropped).

This seems like it would be a common case for handling progress in an Rx Observable since you usually only care about updating your UI with the latest progress information. However I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Anyone know how this can be achieved with RxJava?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onBackPressureLatest` is your friend here. :)
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onBackpressureLatest()

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Apparently I needed to update RxJava. :-P As an added note, I had to call this operator between `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to get it to work.

Comment: Can we get an update on this for RxJava2? I'm trying to use toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST) but it seems to be queueing up all requests and processing those as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.debounce` sounds like what you need. In the example below the latest emission only from observable in each 200ms window will be sent to the observer.

```
observable
    .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: This would work, think I think `onBackPressureLatest` is closer to the original question. `debounce` is bound to the given time frame, which is great for things like UI input.